# Using Next.js 14 next/font causes font not found problem

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fonts

I am trying to load 2 fonts into my website using **next/font/google**. Here is the code:

```
import { Amiri, Figtree } from "next/font/google";

export const fontAmiri = Amiri({
  subsets: ["latin", "arabic"],
  display: "swap",
  style: ["normal"],
  weight: ["400", "700"],
  variable: "--font-amiri",
  preload: true,
});

export const fontFigtree = Figtree({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "swap",
  style: ["normal"],
  weight: ["400", "700"],
  variable: "--font-figtree",
  preload: true,
});
```

However this gives me below errors:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/5f8bef30161d4c4f.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/5575c75be901e827.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/192e369fd43210ef.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/aa4a1f6e4b3986b9.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
localhost/:1 
        
        
       GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/192e369fd43210ef.p.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

and these warnings:

```
localhost/:1 The resource http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/5575c75be901e827.woff2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
localhost/:1 The resource http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/aa4a1f6e4b3986b9.woff2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
localhost/:1 The resource http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/192e369fd43210ef.woff2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
localhost/:1 The resource http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/192e369fd43210ef.p.woff2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
localhost/:1 The resource http://localhost:3000/_next/static/media/5f8bef30161d4c4f.woff2 was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

I have also tried to use **next/font/local** like this:

```
import localFont from "next/font/local";

export const fontAmiri = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "./amiri-regular.ttf",
      weight: "400",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./amiri-bold.ttf",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },
  ],
  variable: "--font-amiri",
});

export const fontFigtree = localFont({
  src: [
    {
      path: "./figtree-regular.ttf",
      weight: "400",
      style: "normal",
    },
    {
      path: "./figtree-bold.ttf",
      weight: "700",
      style: "normal",
    },
  ],
  variable: "--font-figtree",
});
```

this also gives the same errors.

Now when I check the applied fonts, they are correct.
Why are these error thrown and how can I fix this. Thanks.